# the value of a polynomial of degree 1 over $\mathbb Z[x]$ is divisible by infinitely many primes

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here is a problem from Lang's Algebra,chapter 12 and problem 12,

a)Let f(x) be a polynomial of degree 1 in $\mathbb Z[x]$. Show that the values $f(a)$ for $a \in \mathbb Z$ are divisible by infinitely many primes.

b) Let F be a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$ . Show that there are infintely many primes p such that all conjugates of F (in an algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_p$) actually are contained in $\mathbb Q_p$.

So in a) we consider $f(x)= c_0 + c_1 x$. and so $f(a)= c_0 + c_1 a = n$ for some $n \in \mathbb Z$, as $c_0,c_1, a \in \mathbb Z$. Then how can I prove $n$ is divisible by infinitely many primes, where we konw from the Fundamenta theorem of arithmatic that it is divisible by finitely many primes.. I am sure that I am seeing this problem in a wrong way. Show me the right one please.Also say some hints for b).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You misinterprete the problem statement. Maybe this way: For $f\in\mathbb Z[x]$ with $\deg f=1$ there exist infinitely many distinct primes $p_1, p_2,\ldots$ such that there exist integers $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ such that $f(x_i)$ is a multiple of $p_i$.

---

For b) show that any polynomial has a root in $\mathbb F_p$ for infinitely many $p$ and that this can be lifted

Comment: Yeah if it is like this then we don't have anything to prove, but I wrote same as the book.

Comment: @analysis89 There is still something to prove and this is the intended interopretation of the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

Say $f(n)$ is only ever divisible by primes $p_i$, $i \in \{1\dots K\}$. Then $f(n) = \prod p_i^{c_i}$ for some $c_i \in 0 \cup \mathbb N$. You should be able to show that the values of the product on the right are much more sparse than the values of $f$ and thus cannot be equal.

Comment: here $f(n) = k$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$, right? So from here how you can conclude that $k \neq \prod p_i ^ {c_i}$?

Comment: Assume we know that $|f(n)|<M$. Then there are at most $\frac{\ln M}{\ln p_i}$ choices for $c_i$, so all in all $O(\ln^K M)$ candidate values for $f(n)$. But for $0< n\le N$ the function takes $N$ distinct values with $|f(n)|\le |c_1|N+|c_0|$. Since $N\notin O(\ln^K(|c_1|N+|c_0|)=O(\ln^KN)$, we are done.

Comment: I didn't get how you are telling that there is atmost $ln M/{ln p_i}$ choices for $c_i$ and I have no idea about the notation $\bigo (ln^K M)$. If you write a complete answer then I can accept your answer. So if you don't mind can you please explain your points more elaborately? Thanks !

Comment: @analysis89, Take any constant $M$. There are $\frac{M-c_0}{c_1}$ values of $f(n)$, lower than $M$. How many values of $\prod p_i^{c_i}$ lower than $M$ are there? What if this number is less than the number of values $f$ takes in the same interval?